# Python - HTTP post from stdin

Tags: python, bash, http, stdin, ibeacon

I am getting data in this format every second or so from a bash command 'ibeacon_scan"

```
ibeacon scan -b | stdin.py
```

Output:

```
ibeacon scan...
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 4 -71 -69
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 6 2 -71 -63
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 4 -71 -69
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 5 7 -71 -64
```

I need to send that information by query string. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput
import httplib
import urllib

for line in fileinput.input():
   string = line
   string2 = string.split(" ")
   parmas = string2
   parmas = urllib.urlencode({"UUID": "Major","Minor":"RSSI"})
   headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("67.205.14.22")
   conn.request("POST", "post.php", params, headers)
   response = conn.getresponse()
   print response.status, response.reason
   data = response.read()
   print data
   conn.close()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stdin.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn.request("POST", "post.php", params, headers)
NameError: name 'params' is not defined
```

Something is wrong with params? How do I format this to correctly accept the 'ibeacon scan' command and send it by HTTP post?

Comment: `parmas != params` -> close as typo please

Comment: Thank you, sorry it was so simple.

Comment: This is the *same typo* and the *same error* as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25171162/3001761). How can you still not solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in fileinput.input():
   string = line
   string2 = string.split(" ")
   parmas = string2  # you call the variable parmas here
   parmas = urllib.urlencode({"UUID": "Major","Minor":"RSSI"})
   headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("67.205.14.22")
   conn.request("POST", "post.php", params, headers)  # and params here
```

You have made what looks to be a typo.

Comment: Thank you, sorry it was so simple.

Comment: No worries, sometimes you just need a second set of eyes. An IDE would have caught this however so I suggest trying out Pycahrm community edition or Sublime Text 2 with the pylint/flake8 addons.